# What's the physical meaning of the Fourier transform of magnetic flux density?

Tags: electromagnetism, fourier-transform

I have here below the distribution of the magnetic flux density $B$ across a 1 pole pitch in the airgap of a synchronous machine. The horizontal axis represents the distance along the arc length formed by a pole pitch across the airgap.

[image: plot of flux density distribution]

If I take the Fourier Transform of this flux density,how should I interpret the results? I am used to taking Fourier Transform with respect to time and not with respect to spatial data that I have here.

Thanks a lot...

**Update**

I think it makes sense instead to use the Fourier Transform on a complete cycle (i.e. not the half cycle shown up) to look  at the harmonics that we have in the magnetic flux density. This is what I get:

[image]

I guess from the Fourier Transform, this is the only information that is relevant.

Comment: I think that you must have some reason why to use FT **prior** to using it.  FT makes sense only if the quantity is described by differential equation with harmonics as solutions (e.g. differential equation of oscillator)...

Comment: What if I want to look at the harmonic contents?

Comment: That person who has down-voted me should really explain with reason why he/she has done that...and not just leave a negative vote. Be constructive and brave!

Comment: Is that a experimentally measured value?

Comment: Of course you can look at harmonic contents, but what do they mean?  IMHO you should know that **before** making FT...

Comment: @ kso83o Yes it's from a software

Comment: @ Pygmalion This is what I'm asking. What will the FT of spatial data gives on the horizontal axis?

Comment: By the way, your name sounds Celtic...

Comment: @ Pygmalion first time I hear about "sounding" Celtic. Thanks anyway.

Comment: OK, we obviously misunderstand each other.  My point was it has no sense to do FT and then looking for explanation.  It's like: I'll measure brightness of the street lamp and only after that asking, what is this telling me?  That's all.  And BTW I did not downvote you.  Over and out.

Comment: As you can see from the plot, we have a fundamental and then some harmonics. This is why we have a sine-wave like top. So we have a combination of a fundamental B and harmonics. I want to decompose that.

Comment: @ Pygmalion Yes I understand you. But someone told me to do a FT in space to get the fundamental of the fluxwave. Then I was thinking if this makes sense.

Comment: @yCalleecharan Why are you trying to do that? just find the theoretical formula and compare with the plot.

Comment: @ kso83o I know $H=\frac{NI}{g}$ and hence I can get B but this is just one value. I don't know how to get its sinusoidal distribution. The problem is bigger as I am using the B value from my curve to try to get an analytical estimate for my induced voltage. This part is ok but I was asked to look for the fundamental B component as it is the value that gives the fundamental induced voltage.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you probably mean _magnetic_ flux density, is that correct? (If not, please edit the question accordingly.)

Comment: @ David Zaslavsky Yes indeed.

Answer (score 2):

A fourier transform over spatial data gives a spectrum of spatial frequencies. Where a transform of temporal data gives the amplitude versus cycles per second, spatial frequency has units of cycles per meter (or whatever length unit).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see any relevant answers, let me try with this one:

Only you who have intimate knowledge of the problem (experimental setup etc.) could guess, what FT results mean (if anything).  Note: because it is symmetric and resembles cosine function, it isn't neccessary a FT.  *ANY* function can be Fourier transformed, this is just matematical operation, like, let's say, multiplying.

My experimental *guess* would be, that you have **exponential falls at the ends and constant value in the middle**.

Comment: Providing FT data was helpful.  But I really do not see anything significant here.  Low "frequencies" just describe the general shape (cosine-type shape).  Possible high "frequencies" could be significant, but there is nothing.  I'd stick with exponential fall together with a constant.

Comment: Update: If resolution would be higher (larger number of data for FT) maybe some peak at high "frequencies" would distinguish itself.  As it is, all high-frequency contribution seem to be noise.  But don't take my comments for granted, I did used FT on several completely different problems but it was always time-dependent.

Comment: And by the way "frequency" in your case means how often some value oscillates in space - you know, like wave vector $k$ in $\psi = A \sin(k x - \omega t)$.  Which makes me wondering - would you in your experiment expect some kind of standing waves?

Comment: @ Pygmalion Thanks. The flux density distribution I've shown is in the airgap of a synchronous generator. The airgap is the thin air region between the rotating rotor and the stationary armature/stator. I think it's traveling wave as the wave pattern follow the rotor as it moves.

Comment: @yCalleecharan If so, then the idea is that you should have higher harmonics, i.e. $k_1 = 0.25$, $k_2 = 0.5$, $k_n = n \times k_1$, but the resolution is too small to draw such conclusions.

Comment: I am not sure, what you got in your FT graph, usually, $x$-axis corresponds to s$^{-1}$=Hz, in your case it should be m$^{-1}$.  But it says "harmonics"... that I do not understand.  When doing FT, you usually get values for n = 1, 2, 3... and you have to multiply them with certain value to make sense and get proper units.  Have you done that?

Comment: @ Pygmalion Actually I deliberately avoid to have some units on the x axis. The values that you see are the harmonic numbers. The harmonic number is the k index in the FT that varies from 0 to N-1 where N is the data length. My FT plot shows for example that I have a large fundamental component corresponding to harmonic number 1, a very small component for the second harmonic and a slightly larger components for the third harmonic and so on... If a frequency f corresponds to harmonic number 1, then harmonic number 2 corresponds to the frequency 2f.

Comment: $$x(k)= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) \; e^{-j\frac{2 \pi \; n \; k }{N}}, \; k= 0, \: 1, \: \ldots N-1$$ So the harmonic number is the index $k$.

Comment: I am absolutely sure you must give FT its dimensionality and it must be in m$^{-1}$.  Would you like me to calculate the coefficient with which you have to multiply harmonics?  (It is easy procedure but I keep forgetting it and I have to derive that every time from the scratch).

Comment: I take it back.  Suppose you have $N$ numbers at distance $d$, and you do FT on exactly $N$ numbers (FFT is ruled out).  If distance $d$ is also the dimensionality of the space which you expect would confine standing waves, then you *don't* have to do dimensionality.  Numbers transfer directly into harmonics of standing wave.  In all other cases you have to do dimensionality.  It is dead end of my knowledge on your problem.

Comment: @ Pygmalion Thanks for your comments. You seem to have some deep knowledge in this field. I will give myself some time to think more about the problem and will certainly ask around a little. If I get some new information, I will share it here.